# How to obtain all employees leave balances in fewer API calls

Tags: backend, xero-api

I am working on a back-end service that needs to get all employees' leave balances in Xero.

I would like to know if there is a way that allows me to get all employees' leave balances in fewer API calls.

It seems like if I get the employees via the API:
GET https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees

The results do not contain leave balances.

Thus, I have to get all employee objects one by one via:
GET [https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees/{EmployeeID}](https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees/%7BEmployeeID%7D)

In the meantime, because of the API calls limits (60 per minute), I have to wait minutes to get all results, as I need to get more than 100 employees' leave balances.

Is there a way that allows me to get all employees' leave balances in fewer API calls?